# series problem with change of variables

Tags: sequences-and-series

Probably it is a stupid problem, but I can't understand why. I have to sum
$$
\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-(1+q+2n)\tau)e^{-(1+q+2n)\tau}
$$
If I sum over these variables I obtain a result. If I make the substitution
$$
1+q+2n=k
$$
and summing
sum
$$
\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1+q}^{\infty}(1-k\tau)e^{-k\tau}
$$
I obtain another result. Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you fix $q$ as 1 say, then $k$ must be an even integer, but you are summing over *all* integers greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

As @almagest already mentioned, the substitution is not correct because for fixed $q$, $k$ increases in steps of $2$ when $n$ increases in steps of $1$.

To make the summation simpler, try differentiation under summation:

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1−(1+q+2n)\tau) e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau} \\
&= \sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau}
 - \sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+q+2n)\tau e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau} \\
&= \sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau}
 + \sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty
   \tau \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau} \\
&= \left( 1 + \tau \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \right)
   \sum_{q=1}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{−(1+q+2n)\tau} \\
&= \left( 1 + \tau \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \right)
   \left(
    e^{-\tau} \cdot
   \sum_{q=1}^\infty e^{−q\tau} \cdot
   \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{−2n\tau}
   \right)
\end{align}
$$

where $\left( 1 + \tau \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \right) f$ is operator shorthand for $\left( f + \tau \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} \right)$.